# Is it possible to publish apps to Google Play Store that target Android devices back to KitKat?

Tags: android, google-play

I am new to developing Android apps, just started learning.  Deciding to go with a very simple app (game), to start with, for learning purposes, I did some research on the different versions of Android devices, and found as of May 2019, KitKat (Android 4.4 / API 23) still had about 6% of the total devices (which equated at that time to roughly 172.5 million devices).  My thought was this would be a good cutoff/target to build this app.

However, I have since learned that (as of August 1, 2019 for new apps, and November 1, 2019 for updates), Google Play requires a minimum level of Pie (Android 9 / API 28) to be used.

Does this mean that I can not publish an App that supports older devices back to KitKat?  Or am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `targetSdkVersion` is completely separate from the `minSdkVersion` you use as per the [Picking your compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).

While Google Play requires that you target a recent version of Android, you can set your `minSdkVersion` to any value.

Comment: Thanks for the link, very informative, all makes a lot more sense now.  I knew that it didn't make much sense cutting off all the older devices, this makes it a lot more clear.